# How to pull request all the commit history from main to empty branch?

Tags: git, github

Another github user needs to review my code and he said I need to fork from `main` to new branch and delete all commits in this branch, so I could create a pull request with all the code from `main` to this empty branch. How to do this?

Comment: Incoherent. “delete all commits in the empty branch”?? Could you copy and paste what you were actually asked to do?

Comment: why you needed a pull request? you can try using `git rebase` command for review all commits

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed well, thats a requirement not from me :) I also thought about using `git rebase`. Can make a branch without commits this way?

Comment: @John I have no Idea but, you can visit this link hope you get a solution. https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/git-code-review-workflow

Comment: There's no such thing as an *empty* branch, so at least one of you two is confused. :-) Given your self-answer, it seems that he wanted you to create a new GitHib-side branch pointing to one specific commit. That's not an empty branch, though: it contains all commits reachable from the specified commit, ending at the specified commit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
git checkout -d code-review
git reset --hard <sha1 of first commit on github>
git push origin code-review
```